# Printing arguments to a kernel function in dtrace

Tags: network-programming, solaris, dtrace, systemtap

I need to debug my Solaris kernel module particularly extract the data in a structure passed by reference to my kernel function.

```
msg_recv(sk_buff *skbp, uint_t link, uchar_t* src)
{
    pkt_hdr_t *pkt;
    pkt = (pkt_hdr_t *)skbp->data;
    port = pkt->port;    
}
```

I have written a systemtap script in linux to access the argument and extract data.

How can I do this using DTRACE for solaris modules.

I tried looking into the system and trying few commands, but thats all i know about dtrace:

```
[root@vcssx247-ldm7 ~]#dtrace -l | grep msg_recv
 7090        fbt               mymod                     msg_recv1 entry
 7091        fbt               mymod                     msg_recv1 return
 7548        fbt               mymod                     msg_recv entry
 7549        fbt               mymod                     msg_recv return
```

Comment: This is probably relevant:  http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-structs.html

Answer (score 0):

DTrace is similar conceptually to SystemTap (actually, vice versa as SystemTap came later):

1. Like SystemTap, it can attach [probes](http://myaut.github.io/dtrace-stap-book/lang/probes.html) to function, but it requires different syntax:

   ```
   kernel.function("xxx")                 ->    fbt:genunix:xxx:return
   module("mod").function("xxx")          ->    fbt:mod:xxx:entry
   module("mod").function("xxx").return   ->    fbt:mod:xxx:return
   ```
2. Accessing [arguments](http://myaut.github.io/dtrace-stap-book/lang/args.html) is quite different as DTrace doesn't support DWARF for argument names (it has `arg0` .. `arg9` variables which contains `uintptr_t` values of arguments):

   ```
   @cast($skpb, "struct sk_buff", "mod")  ->    ((struct sk_buff*) arg0)
   ```
3. Accessing in-kernel data, is similar, but [printing](http://myaut.github.io/dtrace-stap-book/lang/print.html) functions are different:

   ```
   print($skpb->sk_field)                 ->    trace(args[0]->sk_field)
   print("%32m", $src)                    ->    tracemem(arg2, 32)
   ```

<sup>I've added links to my open book about DTrace/SystemTap where you can find more info</sup>